# can't delete the correct picture from firebase in uicollectionview using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, delete-file

so, I have a collectionview that contains images downloaded from firebase. Each cell has a delete button. Im trying to allow users to delete the images. So far I am able to delete the cell. But then the wrong firebase image is deleted, so when the collectionview is reloaded, it still shows the image that I intend to delete. Please help

```
 var profileImageUrl: String?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! createProfilePicCollectionViewCell
     cell.picCellPic.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: imageUrlArray[indexPath.item])



    profileImageUrl = imageUrlArray[indexPath.item]


    cell.deleteButton?.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.deleteButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteUser(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)


 return cell

}
```

I'm trying to reference the correct image URL using the variable 'profileImageUrl' from the collectionview cell so that I can properly delete them. But it seems like the variable references the wrong URL. Here's the delete function:

```
 @objc func deleteUser(sender:UIButton) {

    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let UID = user.uid

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: self.profileImageUrl!)

        ref.removeValue { error, _ in

        }
    }

    let i = sender.tag
    imageUrlArray.remove(at: i)
    collectionViewController.reloadData()

 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have posted your `profileImageUrl` variable is within the `UIViewController` and not within the `UICollectionViewCell`.

Therefore you're setting it every time a cell is dequeued. I imagine it then always deletes the image at the url from the last cell that was loaded.

Move the `profileImageUrl` variable within the cell class.

Also, your `deleteUser` method in your `UIViewController` or your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass? It may make more sense to have it in the cell class as you need to get a handle on the `profileImageUrl` variable.

Comment: You are exactly right. The same image from the last cell gets deleted repeatedly

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. Hopefully you should solve your problem by moving the property into the cell class and setting it just as you do now but with 'cell.profileImageUrl = '